# Do HTML checkboxes have a default width and height?

Tags: html, css

I've noticed that checkboxes seem to have a default width and height of 13px (using Chrome 89 on a Mac), but I can't find any resources that would confirm this.

Is there a default width and height for checkboxes in HTML or does this depend on the browser and the OS?

Comment: It is browser and device dependent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is depend on the browser & device. check it using  two browsers in same device. &   may change the checkbox height & width according to device pixel rate